# mig layout - span and grow/push spacing

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I want 3 components laid out on 2 lines, so that the bottom component and the top-right component use all available horizontal space.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug, fill"));
Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
cp.add(new JTextField("component 1"), "");
cp.add(new JTextField("component 2"), "growx,push,wrap");
cp.add(new JTextField("component 3"), "span,growx,push");
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Considering the above, how do i stop the space between "component 1" and "component 2" from appearing when resizing the frame?

[image: space problem example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cp.add(new JTextField("component 1"), "");
cp.add(new JTextField("component 2"), "growx,push,wrap");
cp.add(new JTextField("component 3"), "span,growx,pushy");
```

solves this case.